# How is the permutation relationship interpreted

Tags: permutation-cycles

I was given the example as an illustration of structure of permutations in my lecture notes on algebra as shown below:

$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
  2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 7
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ $= (12)(597) = (12)(57)(59) = (12)(36)(68)(36)(38)(57)(59)$

I get the first relationship was obtained by cycle decomposition, but how were 2nd and 3rd relationships obtained? If I may use some hints

Comment: Just as a general tip: this notation is a bit awkward at first, but I encourage you to try writing it out if it is confusing and see how each element is affected, then you'll gain intuition as you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there was any particular general method used.  I should think the point is to show that a given permutation can be written as a product of cycles in many ways.  To find an example you could take a given permutation $\pi$ and a random choice of cycles $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_s$, write
$$\pi=\gamma_1\cdots\gamma_s\sigma\ ,$$
then compute $\sigma$ (and write it as a product of cycles if you like).

The end of your example is possibly useful in that it shows how to write a $3$-cycle as a product of transpositions,
$$(597)=(57)(59)\ ,$$
and the bit in the middle can be interpreted siuilarly,
$$(36)(68)(36)(38)=(683)(386)=(683)(683)^{-1}=\iota\ .$$
But to sum up again, I think it's just a pretty random example.

BTW a cycle can be written as a product of transpositions in many ways, but IMHO the easiest way to remember is not the one used in your example but
$$(a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_2a_3)(a_3a_4)\cdots(a_{n-1}a_n)\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

I will try giving as many details as possible.

Second equality is just the equality $(a_1,\dots,a_n) = (a_1,a_n)(a_1,a_{n-1})\dots(a_1,a_2)$ (which is easy to prove) applied to the second factor. There are many other equalities of the same kind, for example $(a_1,\dots,a_n) = (a_1,a_2)(a_2,a_3)\dots(a_{n-1},a_n)$

Third equality is just multiplying in-between by the 4-terms factor $(36)(68)(36)(38)$, which can be seen to be the identity permutation the following way : $(36)(68)(36) = (38)$ as a special case of $\sigma(a_1,\dots,a_n)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1),\dots,\sigma(a_n))$